# WooCommerce - Restrict API access to user ID

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce, jwt

I'm just getting my feet wet using the REST API in Woocommerce, so any advice is greatly appreciated.
I'm building an app that lets users download their digital products. Authentication is done via JWT.
To retrieve customer downloads I need to use the endpoint **/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/id/downloads**. It seems the only way I can get this endpoint to work is by giving the Customer Role rights to "**list_users**". This works well, but I noticed that the JWT token can be used to access **/wp-json/wc/v3/customers**, which will list all of the customers on the site.
How would I go about filtering the API requests on the Sever side to only display data on the authenticated user?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and [`user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/) to restrict a specific endpoint coupled with the [`rest_endpoints`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_endpoints/) hook which filters the array of available REST API endpoints.

```php
<?php

add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $public_endpoints ) {

    $private_endpoints = array(
        '/wp/v2/users',
        '/wp/v2/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)',
        '/wc/v3/customers',
        '/wc/v3/customers/(?P<id>[\d]+\/download)',
        '/wc/v3/customers/batch',
        //...
    );

    foreach ( $public_endpoints as $public_endpoint => $value ) {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( in_array( $public_endpoint, $private_endpoints, false ) ) {

            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! user_can( $user_id, 'export' ) ) {

                unset( $public_endpoints[$public_endpoint] );

            };

        };

    };

    return $public_endpoints;

} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! The effectively blocks /wp-json/wc/v3/customers from public view. One more question. When I use the full endpoint (/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/id/downloads), I'm still able to change the ID number to anything I want and see another customers downloads. For example, if I'm Customer ID 2, I can enter /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/3/downloads and see the downloads of customer ID 3. Is there any way to restrict the ID to the user from the JWT token?

Comment: Right now I'm giving the customer the permission to "list_users". That seems to be the only way they can access their downloads. Maybe there's a better way to do this as well?

Comment: /wc/v3/customers/(?P<id>[\d]+) seems to work, but /wc/v3/customers/(?P<id>[\d]+)/downloads does not. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: You can have a look at the [Woocomerce REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#batch-update-customers) Apparently there is a batch endpoint too: `/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/batch`. You might want to try `/wc/v3/customers/(?P<id>[\d]+\/download)` I've tested it in a regex tester and it seems to work fine. Don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if I managed to helped you in any way.

Comment: For posterity here is a less radical approach, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109621/3645650