# WordPress: How to make private access to REST API with JWT Auth plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I downloaded, installed and activated the plugin ["JWT Authentication for the WP REST API"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api).

And I see how I can obtain JWT access token when sending credentials from the client.

But I don't see how to use the plugin with the existing WordPress REST API.

For example, if I follow by the link like `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` or `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1`, I still fetch the resource without any restricting the access, so the access is still public.

So how to restrict the access making it private with the plugin?

Comment: My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914508/3645650) would completely unset some of the REST access for specific users. The answer bellow is less radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rest_authentication_errors` hook filter to restrict the REST access coupled with `is_user_logged_in()` and `user_can()`.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {

    if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {

        return $result;

    }

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! user_can( get_current_user_id(), 'export' ) ) {
        
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_not_logged_in',
            __( 'Silence is golden.' ),
            array( 'status' => 401 )
        );

    }

    return $result;

} );
```

Comment: Thanks! You may also add the condition like `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/jwt-auth/') === false` to exclude obtaining the JWT access token when the client sends credentials via POST request

Comment: Then you should probably sanitize the value, `parse_str( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ), $result )`